# How to check for usb device with if statement in bash

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to create an automated bash script that fills up a file with urandom in the unit's flash storage. I can manually use all of the commands to make this happen, but I'm trying to create a script and having difficulty figuring out how to check for the usb device. I know that it will be either sda1 or sdb1, but not sure if the code below is sufficient ...? Thanks! Below, is the code:

```
if /dev/sda1
then
         mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/usbkey
else
         mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/usbkey
fi
```

Comment: The way I script mountable drives is to first put a file on the drive, e.g. "Iamthemountabledrive.txt", then check for the existence of that file. If it isn't there, then I mount the drive. I use this technique to make sure an audio server is mounted for a 5 radio station network, checking every minute in case there is a network interrupt event.

Comment: @MattH How do you check for the existence of the file ("lamthemountabledrive.txt") on a drive within your bash script if the drive is not already mounted?

Comment: `testfile="/dev/usbdrive/Iamthedrive.txt"
if [ -e "$testfile" ]
then
  echo "drive is mounted."
fi`

Comment: What is your platform? On reasonably recent Ubuntu you can expect to find the drive automounted in `/media/<<drivelabel>>` so I would just check for this directory. If it's your only removable device, you can identify it by parsing the output of `mount`. But it would help if you could add more details.

Comment: @triplee embedded ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mount by **label** or **UUID** and hence reduce the complexity of your script. For example if your flash storage has label **MYLABEL** (you can set and display VFAT labels using [mtools](http://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/)' mlabel):

```
$ sudo mount LABEL=MYLABEL /media/usbkey
```

Answer (score 7):

The way I script mountable drives is to first put a file on the drive, e.g. "Iamthemountabledrive.txt", then check for the existence of that file. If it isn't there, then I mount the drive. I use this technique to make sure an audio server is mounted for a 5 radio station network, checking every minute in case there is a network interrupt event.

```
testfile="/dev/usbdrive/Iamthedrive.txt"
if [ -e "$testfile" ]
then
  echo "drive is mounted."
fi
```